# How do I make a Python Flickr GUI?

Tags: python, api, user-interface, python-imaging-library

We’ll be using Web 2.0 APIs for this project. Write a program that displays a wallpaper picture made of Flickr photos about a given topic. That is, the program should:
• Have a GUI that enables the user to enter a topic.
• Query Flickr to gather relevant photos.
• Display a wallpaper picture made of at least 16 different Flickr photos. A loop is required for this task.

This is my project. Does anyone know where to at least begin on this?

We have to use simplejson, PIL, and Python 2.6 to complete this project. It is basically a window that allows input at the top and has a button at the bottom. When a user enters a topic (ex. baseball) and presses the button on the bottom, the GUI will produce one wallpaper with 16 baseball images.

Comment: Can you show how/ what are you thinking about? Some source and then we can help you better

Answer (score 1):

What you would need is. 
1. Ability to fetch all photos about a given topic from flickr, I think the flickr API gives you that option. [This should be a good starting point](http://code.google.com/p/flickrpy/)

1. Stitch at least 16 photos together to form a wall paper using Python Imaging library.
2. Display these photos together.